# Attempting to insert <a href="http://www.chateauversailles.fr/"</a> into a Google Map InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps

Trying to insert an active link into a Google Marker title using the below code.
href

{ title: 'Palace of Versailles, France ', location: { lat: 48.804865, lng: 2.120355 } }

After "Palace of Versailles, France" a href was inserted.

When the marker is clicked on only "Palace of Versailles, France" appears in the title, no link. Inserting text lines other than href works just fine.

I tried several other href formats but no success. Also using css to customize title presentation/format which would not affect href.

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor in your title is correct, you are missing the closing `>` before `</a>`

`<a href=“http://www.chateauversailles.fr/"></a>`